# how to prevent this border-right from going beyond the div?

Tags: html, css, border

```css
.secundaria {
  width: 500px;
  height: 610px;
  background-color: #c32929;
  margin-top: 90px; /* Margem negativa igual à altura do polígono SVG */
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
        <div class="secundaria">
            <div class="empty-container">
                <svg height="100%" width="100%">
                  <polyline points="0,0 0,40 138,40 158,75 500,75 500,0 0,0" style="fill: #FFE18D; stroke: none; stroke-width: 3"></polyline>
                  <polyline points="0,40 138,40 158,75 500,75" style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 3"></polyline>
                </svg>
              </div>
        </div>
```

i have this css and this html block, how can i prevent the border on the right from leaving the div ?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that the `5px` border makes the `500px` wide element `505px` wide in total, there are two solutions:

- make the element `495px` wide so that 495+5 = 500
- use `box-sizing: border-box;`

I recommend using the following:

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here's an example of it in action where it logs out the actual widths to the console with and without the `box-sizing` applied

```js
const widthOne = document.querySelector('#one').getBoundingClientRect().width;
const widthTwo = document.querySelector('#two').getBoundingClientRect().width;
console.log(widthOne, widthTwo);
```

```css
.secundaria {
  width: 500px;
  height: 610px;
  background-color: #c32929;
  margin-top: 90px; /* Margem negativa igual à altura do polígono SVG */
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
}

.sized-to-border {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="secundaria" id="one">
    <div class="empty-container">
        <svg height="100%" width="100%">
          <polyline points="0,0 0,40 138,40 158,75 500,75 500,0 0,0" style="fill: #FFE18D; stroke: none; stroke-width: 3"></polyline>
          <polyline points="0,40 138,40 158,75 500,75" style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 3"></polyline>
        </svg>
      </div>
</div>

<div class="secundaria sized-to-border sized-to-border" id="two">
    <div class="empty-container">
        <svg height="100%" width="100%">
          <polyline points="0,0 0,40 138,40 158,75 500,75 500,0 0,0" style="fill: #FFE18D; stroke: none; stroke-width: 3"></polyline>
          <polyline points="0,40 138,40 158,75 500,75" style="fill: none; stroke: black; stroke-width: 3"></polyline>
        </svg>
      </div>
</div>
```